# How to set the maximum width of a flow-layouted JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, flowlayout

[image]

As the picture shows: Outer is JPanel_1 with `BorderLayout`; Left is JPanel_2 on the west of the JPanel_1, and it uses `GridBadLayout`; In JPanel_2 are several panels, each containing several `JButton`.

The problem is, as JPanel_3 uses `FlowLayout`, I tried to set it with a maximum width so that the buttons auto change line when there are too many. However, whichever `JPanel` to set with either `size`, `maximumSize`, `preferred size`， it doesn't work. The buttons stays at one line, making the JPanel too wide for me.

Anyone has a solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extend FlowLayout to restrict preferred width like this

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class TestMaxWidthFlowLayout {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f=new JFrame();
        JPanel pButtons=new JPanel(new FlowLayout() {
            public Dimension preferredLayoutSize(Container target) {
                Dimension sd=super.preferredLayoutSize(target);

                sd.width=Math.min(200, sd.width);

                return sd;
            }
        });
        for (int i=0;i<20; i++) {
            pButtons.add(new JButton("b-"+i));
        }

        f.add(pButtons, BorderLayout.WEST);
        f.add(new JLabel("center"), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        f.setSize(500, 300);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> so that the buttons auto change line when there are too many.

You can use the [Wrap Layout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/06/wrap-layout/). It will dynamically flow components to a new line as the available width changes.

WrapLayout is an extension of FlowLayout that will correctly calculate the preferred size of the panel as the components wrap.

Comment: I tried yours, still some problems with the tabbedPane. So I finally extend FlowLayout myself, inspired by you and SanisiavL.